# Is there a built-in C# type that allows deferred execution, but not casting back to IQueryable?

Tags: c#, generic-collections, deferred-execution

Is there a recommended built-in type in C# that collections can be converted/cast to that will still allow deferred execution, but not allow the type to be cast back into IQueryable? (Like `IEnumerable<T>` can in some cases)

Comment: I don't know of a built-in one, but since it can be two lines of code in one function, why not do it yourself?

Comment: You should have a look at the yield return statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A built in type no but it's pretty easy to do :

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> AsDefferedEnumerable<T>(this IQueryable<T> Source)
    {
        foreach (var item in Source)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

This way you're not returning a casted IQueryable (that could be casted back) but creating a new IEnumerable wrapping it , you don't even need a new type at all for that you just end up with an IEnumerable that will itself enumerate the IQueryable as it is enumerated without exposing it.

Edit : sample of a wrapper object (untested)

```
public class HideImplementationEnumerable<T>
{
public HideImplementationEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> Source)
{
    this.Source = Source;
}

private IEnumerable<T> Source;

public IEnumerable<T> Value
{
    get
    {
        foreach (var item in Source)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, but my reason for wanting a different type was so a code reviewer could see at a glance that the return type is something that code downstream cannot alter the query with.

Comment: @adam0101 That sounds unecessary, if a code reviewer sees an IEnumerable all he should assume is that he can enumerate it, but changing this to a type is trivial, editing my answer now for a type version (a type also has other advantages, it is pretty useless to do "just that" but it can be extended to do caching etc.)*

Answer (score 4):

The "built in" way to guard `IQueryable<T>` would be `Enumerable.Select` like this

```
IQueryable<T> source = ...;
var result = source.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x);
```

`AsEnumerable` is not enough because it is a simply cast. But it's needed to ensure `Enumerable.Select` is used instead of `Queryable.Select`.

However, other than being "built in", I see no benefit of this approach and prefer the custom extension method like in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866250/is-there-a-built-in-c-sharp-type-that-allows-deferred-execution-but-not-casting/34866332#34866332), although this can be used as implementation instead of iterator function (which also has no benefit, but rather a drawback due to unnecessary delegate call, so really the custom iterator function is the right way to go).

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary You are welcome. And btw, glad to see you posting again!